# Read line of different type into

Tags: c++, input, inputstream

The file format looks like:

```
A 1 2 3
B 1 2 3
...
```

And I want to read them in a vector of struct Observation that looks like:

```
struct Observation {
    string category;
    vector<int> variables;
};
```

How can I read them? I've searched for some solutions here, and tried:

```
int main() {
    ifstream infile("data.txt");
    string line;
    string category;
    vector<Observation> obs;
    int i = 0;
    while(getline(infile, line)) {
        istringstream iss(line);
        iss >> category;
        int j = 0;
        int value;
        while(iss >> value) {
            obs[i].variables[j] = value;
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

but it says: error: variable ‘std::istringstream iss’ has initializer but incomplete type my compilier is g++ 4.6.3 on Ubuntu 12.04, complie with command "g++ -std=c++0x io.cpp -g -o io", please help me with that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including `<sstream>` and also change the way you add to the vector:

```
while(iss >> value) {
    obs[i].variables.push_back(value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it complies, but when I run, it says "command terminated" what could be the problem?

Comment: @Bamqf How are you running your program ? Is that all the code ? You're not checking if the file is opened correctly. Are you sure it's not missing or something ?

Comment: Yes it's all the file, except for the include, and I use gdb to track it, it says:Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000401202 in std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::push_back (this=0x8, 
    __x=@0x7fffffffdc68: 1) at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h:828
828  if (this->_M_impl._M_finish != this->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage)

Comment: Oh I get it, obs has to use push_back to, I haven't initialize but use obs[i] to get its element, thank you!